# Advanced System.Transactions debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, transactionscope

Are there any tips, tricks or methods for obtaining profiling/logging/debug information on the runtime behaviour of `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`?

I have an application which is committing data to the database, even though I'm using `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`, where an exception is thrown and `TransactionScope.Commit()` is never called.

I was wondering if there are events or details on other classes used by `TransactionScope` that I can query at runtime to establish whether my commands (typed data adapters) are enlisting the ambient transaction or not.

Having looked at `System.Transactions.dll` using Reflector, I think the `System.Transactions.Diagnostics` namespace might help, but any examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check-out this article: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/madhuponduru/system-transactions-trace)

Add following info to your application config file to trace System.Transactions calls

```
<configuration>
 <system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
   <source name="System.Transactions" switchValue="Information">
   <listeners>
    <add name="tx" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData= "tx.log" />
   </listeners>
  </source>
 </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

MORE INFO:
once you got trace file, you can open the trace in SvcTraceViewer.exe
You can enable MSDTC transaction trace,CM trace to know more about transaction also
Reference:

- http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229979.aspx
- http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678891.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926099/
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/898918/

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a transaction scope with parameters?

This behaviour would be expected for transaction scope option of Supress.

Otherwise could you post some code.